# If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then $2a \in B$ and $2b \in A$ and $(a+b)^{2014}\in C$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Below are questions that it think I know how to do but im not $100\%$ sure.

$(i)$ 
asks if $a$ is odd so $a=k+1$, then prove $2a$ is even so $2a = 2k+2.$ The second and third differ a little am I thinking correctly or is there a better way to do it?

Let $A = \{3k + 1 \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}, B = \{3k + 2 \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $C = \{3k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where the
universal set is $E = Z.$

$(i)$ If $m \in A$, prove that $2m \in B$.

$(ii)$ If $n \in B$, prove that $2n \in A.$

$(iii)$ If $m \in A$ and $n \in B$, prove that $(m + n)^{2014} \in C.$

Comment: What are A, B and C?

Comment: they are sets shown in the image above

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $m \in A$, then $m=3k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $2m=6k+2=3(2k)+2$. Since this is of the form $3s+2$, therefore $2m \in B$.

Comment: @ Anurag A, Thank you I thought of trying that but i thought it was too simple so i left it.

Comment: @Daniel It *is* simple... but effective :) That's really all there is to part (i).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**(for doing this in a better way)

Let $m \in A$ and $n \in B$

$i)$ $m \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow 2m \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

$ii)$ $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow 2n \equiv 4 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow 2n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

$iii)$ $m+n \equiv 3 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow m+n \equiv 0\pmod 3 \Rightarrow (m+n)^{2014} \equiv 0 \pmod 3$

---

**Note:**

$\text{mod }$ stands for modulo. It gives the remainder when a number is divided by another. For example, $5$ divided by $3$ gives the remainder as $2$. So, $5 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.